# Extracting texts contained in a html tag with a copyright symbol © using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to check if a webpage has a copyright  symbol © and if so, I extract texts of the tag containing the symbol. For instance, for the webpage "profile.theguardian.com/signin" the targeted texts are "© 2018 Guardian News and Media Limited or its affiliated companies. All rights reserved". How can it be done using Python 3.x?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution I was looking for;

```
URL = 'https://profile.theguardian.com/signin'
webpage = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content,'html.parser')
symbol = u'\N{COPYRIGHT SIGN}'.encode('utf-8')
symbol = symbol.decode('utf-8')
pattern = r'' + symbol
for tag in soup.findAll(text=re.compile(pattern)):
        copyrightTexts = tag.parent.text
        print(copyrightTexts)
```

Hopefully this will help others. Thanks for those who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should post your sample code when you submit your question, but the following should tell if the copyright sign is on a particular page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request


masterURL = 'https://profile.theguardian.com/signin'

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(masterURL).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')
temp = soup.prettify().encode('UTF-8')

#\xc2\xa9 is unicode symbol for copyright sign

if(b'\xc2\xa9' in temp):
     print('Copy Right On Page')
else:
     print('No Copy Right on Page')
```

Answer (score -1):

Taking that as the `footer_copyright` you can do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as url
BeautifulSoup(url.urlopen(masterURL).read()).select("p.footer__copyright")
```

Comment: your solution is specific to this webpage but copyright info can be placed in different tags as well as attributes. So I wanted a generic code that will search using a symbol.